# Django create common "createObject" view logic

Tags: django

I've got a django app with multiple models, and mostly crud functionalities. Most of my views are very similar, ie. for example, all ModelnameCreate  functions have very similar structure.
So I decided to make helper function: (here is an example of helper for creating new objects)

```
def createFuncHelper(request, title_label , formClass , form_render  , success_render  , renderToViewWithId , success_message):
  
    form = formClass()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = formClass(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.updatedBy = request.user
            newObject = form.save()
            messages.success(request, success_message)
            if(renderToViewWithId):
                return redirect(success_render, id=newObject.pk)
            else:
                return redirect(success_render) 
    return render(request, form_render, {'form':form, 'title_label':title_label})
```

Which is called from my each view (for each model) eg.:

```
def BookingCreate(request):
    return createFuncHelper(request, etc...
```

It works, but the question for my more experience collegues is - if it is the right approach, or are there any serious risks I'm not aware?

Comment: Have you considered using [Django's class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views-1)? They basically do what you're describing here. You may not need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: thanks!! hmm, it seemed to me - such (mine) approach has better flexibility, or maybe I do not understand class-based views enough, to know how to implement there my parts - like that updatedBy etc

Comment: `updatedBy` would probably be set in a subclass version of [`CreateView.form_valid`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#form_valid).